# Call to DB returning incomplete data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen

I have an SQL Query:

```
select count(*) AS revolutions, DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as time_period from `raw_data` where `time` >= '2016-09-10 21:51:33' group by `time_period`
```

This returns the following data in a MySQL client:

```
revolutions | time_period
630         | 2016-09-10 23
2062        | 2016-09-11 00
1839        | 2016-09-11 01
377         | 2016-09-11 02
83          | 2016-09-11 03
325         | 2016-09-11 04
```

In Laravel, I build an identical query that a dump of looks like this:

```
["sql"]=>
  string(136) "select count(*) AS revolutions, DATE_FORMAT(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as time_period from `raw_data` where `time` >= ? group by `time_period`"
  ["bindings"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(19) "2016-09-10 22:02:02"
  }
```

but this returns the following set of data:

```
[
  {

    "revolutions": 1863,
    "time_period": "2016-09-10 22"
  },
  {
    "revolutions": 1839,
    "time_period": "2016-09-10 23"
  },
  {
    "revolutions": 377,
    "time_period": "2016-09-11 00"
  },
  {
    "revolutions": 83,
    "time_period": "2016-09-11 01"
  },
  {
    "revolutions": 325,
    "time_period": "2016-09-11 02"
  }
]
```

What could be causing the missing data on 02, and the non-existent data on 03 and 04?

Edit: Time zone was not set in Lumen.

Fix was to add a config value to the .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_TIMEZONE=+02:00
```

Comment: those 2 data sets are quite difirent

Comment: "I build an identical query" --- unless it's not: the time parameter holds different value.

Comment: @zerkms the time parameter shouldnt matter for this. As both as set to find data from the past forward.

Comment: @nogad good point.

Comment: "the time parameter shouldnt matter for this" --- you're making an assumption that we are familiar with your data. We are not. If you state something is identical - make sure it is identical, or use some different wording.

Comment: @zerkms I thought it quite obvious what the time >= was doing. But yes, I should have been more specific about the differences.

Comment: So, wrong database then? :-)

Comment: @zerkms both the mysql query and the Laravel query pull from the same live database and table, with the same mysql user.

Comment: looks more diffident than the same, are you sure both queries are identical? both data sets are the same ?

Comment: Seems that result with id 1863 is valid on the second query since the time parameter is different. Not a valid question imho.

Comment: @iliaz Maybe, but why is future data also different or missing?

Comment: Any chance `time` column is of type `timestamp`? If so, the answer would be "both clients have different timezone set".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `time` is of `timestamp` type, which converts the time into a timezone that the client should specify explicitly right after they connected.

To set it explicitly one must emit the

```
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

query.

And the default value comes from the config (or CLI parameters) directive `default-time-zone`

References:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html

Comment: You sir, Are a time saver!